# Struggling with rapid api and swiftui

Tags: xcode, api, swiftui, rapidapi

Hi I am struggling with getting football data api from rapidapi to work in swift ui . here is the code below

The errors is get are "self.team = decodedTeams" Cannot find 'self' in scope"

and in my content view i get for " $network.getTeams"
Value of type 'EnvironmentObject.Wrapper' has no dynamic member 'getTeams' using key path from root type 'Network'

I have set out what i have in 2 pages of my swiftui code below
any help would be appreciated, I am really struggling with this one

```
//  Network.swift
//  Football Scores
//

//

import Foundation

class Network: ObservableObject {
        @Published var teams: [Team] = []

}
func getTeams() {
let headers = [
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "MY API KEY",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
]`

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/standings?season=2022&league=39")! as URL,
                                  cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        print(httpResponse)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                          do {
                              let decodedTeams = try JSONDecoder().decode([Team].self, from: data)
                              self.team = decodedTeams
                          } catch let error {
                              print("Error decoding: ", error)
                          }
                      }
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
}
```

and

```
//
//  Team.swift
//  Football Scores
//

//

import Foundation

struct Team: Identifiable, Decodable {
var id: Int
var name: String
var logo: String
var points: String
var goaldif: String
}
```

and

```
//  Football_ScoresApp.swift
//  Football Scores
//


import SwiftUI
import Foundation


@main

struct Football_ScoresApp: App {

var network = Network()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
    
        ContentView()
                                       .environmentObject(network)
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var network: Network


var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
                    Text("All teams")
                    .font(.title).bold()
            }
            .onAppear {
                network.getTeams()
            }
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(network.teams) { team in
            HStack(alignment:.top) {
                Text("\(team.id)")

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(team.name)
                        .bold()

                   
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
            .padding()
            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6667672396, green: 0.7527905703, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2662717301)))
            .cornerRadius(20)
        }
    }
    
}



}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(Network())
    
}
}
```

Comment: And what's your issue? Did you get the response? `self.team = decodedTeams` is called? `print("Error decoding: ", error)` is called?

Comment: self.teams = decoded teams gives me cannot find 'self, in scope

Comment: Unrelated, avoid using `NS(Mutablle)Stuff` when `Stuff`: `NSMutableURLRequest` -> `URLRequest`, `NSURL` -> `URL`, etc.

Comment: `func getTeams()` isn't inside `class Network`. it's currently "nowhere"

Comment: I've updated my post with the errors, Ive just added 'func getTeams()' to class network, The error i get now is self.team = decodedTeams is Value of type'network' has no momber team

Comment: Where is the SwiftUI code?

Comment: Ive added some more code to the post

Comment: the error you get is because you should be using `self.teams = decodedTeams`, note the `s` in `self.teams`. You should also use `guard let data = data else { return }` just before `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}`.

Comment: Thank you, that solves all the errors 
now the only issue i have is nothing is displaying in the iphone simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the `teams` from your api request, first you need to create a set of struct models that
represent the json data that the server is sending. From the server response, you need to
extract the `teams` information you want to display. Here is my code
that shows how to do it, works well for me, pay attention to the details:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var network = Network() // <-- for testing

    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(network.teams) { team in
                    HStack(alignment:.top) {
                        Text("\(team.id)")
                        Text(team.name).bold()
                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6667672396, green: 0.7527905703, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2662717301)))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            network.getTeams()
        }
    }
    
}

class Network: ObservableObject {
    @Published var teams: [Team] = []
    
    func getTeams() {
        let token = "your-key"  // <--- here your api key

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/standings?season=2022&league=39") else { return }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-RapidAPI-Key")
        request.setValue("api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-RapidAPI-Host")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(FootyResponse.self, from: data)
                    // extract just the teams
                    for response in results.response {
                        for stand in response.league.standings {
                            for league in stand {
                                self.teams.append(league.team)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error) // <-- here important
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
  
}

// MARK: - FootyResponse
struct FootyResponse: Codable {
    let welcomeGet: String
    let parameters: Parameters
    let errors: [String]
    let results: Int
    let paging: Paging
    let response: [Response]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case welcomeGet = "get"
        case parameters, errors, results, paging, response
    }
}

// MARK: - Paging
struct Paging: Codable {
    let current, total: Int
}

// MARK: - Parameters
struct Parameters: Codable {
    let league, season: String
}

// MARK: - Response
struct Response: Codable {
    let league: League
}

// MARK: - League
struct League: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let logo: String
    let flag: String
    let season: Int
    let standings: [[Standing]]
}

// MARK: - Standing
struct Standing: Codable {
    let rank: Int
    let team: Team
    let points, goalsDiff: Int
    let group: String
    let form: String
    let status: String
    let standingDescription: String?
    let all, home, away: All
    let update: String  // <-- Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rank, team, points, goalsDiff, group, form, status
        case standingDescription = "description"
        case all, home, away, update
    }
}

// MARK: - All
struct All: Codable {
    let played, win, draw, lose: Int
    let goals: Goals
}

// MARK: - Goals
struct Goals: Codable {
    let goalsFor, against: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case goalsFor = "for"
        case against
    }
}

// MARK: - Team
struct Team: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let logo: String
}
```

EDIT-1:

to get the `points` of each `team`, you need to use the `Standing` struct. Here is an **example** code to do that.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var network = Network()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach(network.stand) { stand in  // <-- here
                    HStack(alignment:.top) {
                        Text(stand.team.name).bold()  // <-- here
                        Text("\(stand.points) points")  // <-- here
                    }
                    .frame(width: 300, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6667672396, green: 0.7527905703, blue: 1, alpha: 0.2662717301)))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            network.getTeams()
        }
    }
    
}

class Network: ObservableObject {
    @Published var teams: [Team] = []
    
    @Published var stand: [Standing] = []  // <-- here
    
    func getTeams() {
        let token = "your-key"  // <--- here your api key

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/standings?season=2022&league=39") else { return }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-RapidAPI-Key")
        request.setValue("api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-RapidAPI-Host")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(FootyResponse.self, from: data)
                    // extract the teams and the standings
                    results.response.forEach{ response in
                        response.league.standings.forEach{ stand in
                            self.stand = stand  // <--- here
                            stand.forEach{ league in
                                self.teams.append(league.team)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error) // <-- here important
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
  
}

// MARK: - Standing
struct Standing: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()  // <-- here
    let rank: Int
    let team: Team
    let points, goalsDiff: Int
    let group: String
    let form: String
    let status: String
    let standingDescription: String?
    let all, home, away: All
    let update: String  // <-- Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case rank, team, points, goalsDiff, group, form, status
        case standingDescription = "description"
        case all, home, away, update
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying for a few days now to figure out how to extract each teams points as well, are you able to help and show me?

Comment: Updated my answer with some example code to show how to extract each teams points.

Comment: Perfect thank you for your help, I am now nearly finished my app due to the help you gave

Comment: Last question I am creating a navigation view, how to pass the info into that view? I have extracted all of the info i need for the app now

Comment: `the info` is contained in your `class Network: ObservableObject{...}`, so pass it to 
other views using for example `@EnvironmentObject var network: Network`, from `ContentView` with `.environmentObject(network)`.
Read the very useful info on this subject here:  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app  in particular the section `Share an object throughout your app`